# error loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0

Tags: libraries

A whole pile of my applications are no longer launching (xchat, vmware, etc) with this error.

```
xchat: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did some searching and tried a few of the posts found (on this site and others) but I can't seem to get past this. I checked in /`usr/lib/x86_64-linux_gnu` -- assuming that is where it wants to find the file -- and sure enough there is no entry. I'm just not sure how to put it there.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is this a 64 bit system?  Are the programs having problems 64 bit?

Comment: Yes on both fronts. All these programs were working -- clearly _I_ did something I wasn't supposed to. I was trying to get netExtender for a WebVPN working a few days back. Something I did then must have caused this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstall the package `libssl1.0.0`

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:amd64
```

The 64 bit shared library should be at

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

with a link to it at

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

The static library is at

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
```

If it's just the links missing, you can replace them yourself without doing a package reinstall.

---

Looks like the file was deleted (or moved --see if locate libssl.so.1 finds it).  Of course, the package manager would know nothing about that, so try the -f force on the install, and if that fails, try the apt-get  --reinstall switch.

Comment: Hi ubfan, ... I ran the package installer command and the feedback I got was that libssl1.0.0 was already at the newest version. I checked /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 and the file was not there, however the other two you referenced we're there. In fact the second one showed up as lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       37 Jun 11 11:32 libssl.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 .. but the fact that the file it is linking to is not there I suppose is the issue. Can I force it to install even it "it is already there"? (OS seems to be confused)

Comment: The --reinstall flag did the trick. I didn't even know that was an option. Thanks so much ubfan1

Comment: Where should I get `libssl1.0.0`from? It's not in my sources and the only other option i get is libssl3.

Comment: @Kyo Kazuto Look in https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: I experienced a similar problem setting up a new system (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, openssl 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8). and successfully applied ubfan1's solution. Is the lack of a symlink a bug in the openssl (or some other) package?

Comment: @nanobotic You should ask your own question.  This answer predates the combination of /lib and /usr/lib, so doesn't fully apply to current releases.